# How to serialize typescript object to firebase?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I've an issue:
In my angular app, I'm using a lot of classes with inheritance, but I just noticed that when trying to save those objects to firebase, I get an error saying that I'm trying to persist some customs objects and that isn't supported.

Here is the error:

```
ERROR FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data (via `toFirestore()`). Unsupported field value: a custom object (found in field itinerary in document trips/iLK63UGEsYpZbn2NG2N7)
    at new n (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:39963:23)
    at Gu (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:53855:16)
    at t.i_ (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:53575:16)
    at Mu (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:53808:37)
    at Uu (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:53692:50)
    at http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:53792:17
    at _ (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:40153:68)
    at Cu (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:53791:56)
    at Ru (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:53616:19)
    at n.set (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:55193:40)
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:5980
```

How to serialize them then?

Because I've some complex objects and they will have some good helper method and I don't see an easy way to convert my model.

Here is the minimum model for now:

```
export class Trip {
  id: string;
  owner: string;
  name: string;
  startDate: Date;
  endDate: Date | undefined;
  coverImageUrl: string;
  itinerary: Itinerary;

  constructor() {
    this.itinerary = new Itinerary();
  }
}

export class Itinerary {
  stats: ItineraryStats;
  steps: Step[];

  constructor() {
    this.steps = Step[0];
    this.stats = new ItineraryStats();
  }
}

export class ItineraryStats {
  duration: number;
  driveTime: number;
  driveDistance: number;

  averageDriveDistancePerDay(): number {
    return this.driveDistance / this.duration;
  }
  averageDriveTimePerDay(): number {
    return this.driveTime / this.duration;
  }
}


export abstract class Step {
  start: Date;
  end: Date;
  duration: number;
  enforcedStartStop: boolean;
  warning: string;
}
export abstract class StopStep extends Step {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  pointOfInterest: PointOfInterest | null;
  address: string;
  coordinates: firebase.firestore.GeoPoint;
}


export class ActivityStep extends StopStep {
  duration: number;

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.id = Guid.newGuid();
  }
}


export class NightStep extends StopStep {
  nightNumber: number;
  numberOfNight: number;
}

export class PointOfInterest {
  type: PointOfInterest;
}


export class TravelStep extends Step {
  Mode: TravelMode;
  PolyLines: string;
}
```

I'm trying to save a Trip here.

I'm using NGXS + Angular fire, but the error would be the same with only angularfire I guess.

I tried to use a library(classToPlain) that converts typescript to json, but it was not working because some objects were objects of Firebase that were supposed to stay class(GeoPoint) and not be transformed.

Comment: Can you add your tries and the error massage to help others replicate the issue?

Comment: @vitooh I added more information :)

Comment: why don’t you convert the typescript to simple json using JSON.stringify and while reading use copyInto to form the typescript object from the json ?

Comment: because I've not one level of classes but severals, and some fields are collection of an abstract object. But if you know how to do this with JSON.stringify, I would be more than happy to see how you proceed?

Comment: `JSON.stringify` will serialize deep objects. But the question is, how would you deserialize that thing, as you don't know the proper type abstract type `Step` inside `Itinerary` class. Your step array inside `Itinerary` class becoming heterogenous, which causes all the problems.

Comment: @RatulSharker There has to be a way. `class-transformer` was handling that part by saving one additional field with the type of the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to create `toJSON` and `fromJSON` in `Trip` class and use `JSON.stringify` as Ratul Sharker suggested. Doing that, you will be able to control the 'complexity' of you object and what you want to use or not in your FB message.

[More information here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

## Update

First of all, I would create a `type` property in `Step` class and a constructor to force all descendants to assing its type. Thus we will have all the information needed to rebuild our object, also would create a static function -let's call it `CreateFromJS` to rebuild a step from a pure JS object:

```
export enum StepTypes {
  Unkown=0,
  Stop=1,
  Activity=2,
  Night=3,
  Travel=4
}

export abstract class Step {
  start: Date;
  end: Date;
  duration: number;
  enforcedStartStop: boolean;
  warning: string;
  type: StepTypes;

  constructor(type:StepTypes) {
     this.type=type;
  }
  
  static createFromJS(obj: any) {
    let step=null;

    switch(obj.type) {
        case StepTypes.Unkown:
        case StepTypes.Stop:
            // ERROR!
            break;

        case StepTypes.Activity:
            step=new ActivityStep();
            break;

        case StepTypes.Night:
            step=new NightStep();   
            break;

        case StepTypes.Travel:
            step=new TravelStep();
            break;
    }

    if(step) {
        Object.assign(step, obj);
    } else {
        step=obj;
    }

    return step;
  }
}
```

Then in all Step classes would add a constructor to determine its type:

```
export abstract class StopStep extends Step {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  pointOfInterest: PointOfInterest | null;
  address: string;
  coordinates: GeoPoint;

  constructor() {
    super(StepTypes.Stop);
  }
}

export class ActivityStep extends StopStep {
  duration: number;

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.type=StepTypes.Activity;
    this.id = 'Guid.newGuid()';
  }
}


export class NightStep extends StopStep {
  nightNumber: number;
  numberOfNight: number;

 constructor() {
    super();
    this.type=StepTypes.Night;
  } 
} 

export class TravelStep extends Step {
  Mode: TravelMode;
  PolyLines: string;
  constructor() {
    super(StepTypes.Travel);
  } 
 }
```

And finally in `Trip` class would add function to convert the object to pure JS and the same to restore it from pure JS:

```
export class Trip {
  id: string;
  owner: string;
  name: string;
  startDate: Date;
  endDate: Date | undefined;
  coverImageUrl: string;
  itinerary: Itinerary;

  constructor() {
    this.itinerary = new Itinerary();
  }

  getJSObject() {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this));
  }

  static createFromJS(fb:any):Trip {
    const trip:Trip=new Trip();

    Object.assign(trip, fb);

    for(let i=0;i<trip.itinerary.steps.length;i++) {
        trip.itinerary.steps[i]=Step.createFromJS(trip.itinerary.steps[i]);
    }

    return trip;
  }
}
```

As Firebase doesn't allow custom objects we will have to convert to pure JS before storing them so when you store the trip to firebase you must call `getJSObject` and store the returnet value.

And when you restore object from store you oonly have to create it using the static method `createFromJS` that will restore custom types.

To test it just have to create a trip and add some steps... and try our new functions, we can check in the console that first Trip has type then `jst` has not type (that should work on Firebase) and finally restoring it from the pure JS with its types again... so:

```
const trip=new Trip();
const actStep=new ActivityStep();
const nightStep=new NightStep();
const travelStep=new TravelStep();

Object.assign(trip, {id:'id', coverImageUrl:'url', name:'name', owner: 'owner', startDate:new Date(2021, 5, 10), endDate: new Date(2021, 5, 12)});
Object.assign(trip.itinerary.stats, {driveDistance:100, driveTime: 10, duration: 2});

actStep.address='address';
actStep.description='Desc';
actStep.duration=50;
actStep.enforcedStartStop=false;
actStep.pointOfInterest=new PointOfInterest;

trip.itinerary.steps.push(actStep, nightStep, travelStep);

const jst=trip.getJSObject();
const parsed=Trip.createFromJS(jst);

console.log(trip);
console.log(jst);
console.log(parsed);
```

## Update 2

To avoid using `type` property in custom classes just delete `type` property and replace `getJSONObject` function in `Trip`class for this:

```
getJSObject() {
    const json=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this));
    let type;

    for(let i=0;i<this.itinerary.steps.length;i++) {
        switch(this.itinerary.steps[i].constructor.name) {
            case 'ActivityStep':
                type=StepTypes.Activity;
                break;

            case 'NightStep':
                type=StepTypes.Night;                   
                break;

            case 'TravelStep':
                type=StepTypes.Travel;
                break;

            default:
                type=0;
        }
        // Set type in pure JS...
        json.itinerary.steps[i].type=type;
    }

    return json;
}
```

As we have the same object... the index of itineraries are the same so we get type from our object and replace it in pure JS one...

Comment: Hi, thank you for the feedback. How would you proceed to serialize the `Itinerary`, which has an array of `Step`. Step being an abstract class, I need to know which one has been serialized. Because I would not know which `fromJSON` to call? 

Can you show an example? Like for the Itinerary class by example?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I get your point. Do you think we can avoid having this "type" on the typescript object? It should be only serialized on the javascript version I guess?

Comment: Yes, I think it can be avoided setting it in `getJSObject`, iterating over `steps` and setting `type` on pure JS returned object... the same it's done when recreating.

Comment: I will test this when I get home, thanks :)

Comment: I'm currently check for the real implementation, but since generate the whole thing to JSON in one method(JSON.Stringify), I'm not sure how I can step in and add information(like the step type) ? Is there a way to make this JSON.Stringify/parse not doing a "deep" copy, and then having the "getJSObject" method on each level? I cannot find how to NOT make a deep copy?

Comment: I think it's easier without controlling the deep copy (that is done using `toJSON` let me update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update 2. The thing is, I have those steps(and other similar types) in severals places, so it would be better if this logic could stay inside the Step(or its descendant).

Comment: I just found that if the item has a "toJSON" method, it will be called instead of the default method. WOuldn't that be a solution?

Comment: Yes that was my initial answer... and no... because you will have to control what are you parsing and what not... the proposed solution (update 2) you won't have to care about the descendant class and type because all will be centralized in two functions and not in descentant class...  you will have to create `toJSON` for each `Step`... maybe is not as elegant as we wanted to be. :)

Comment: I've made some progress inspired by your work: https://codepen.io/jgrossrieder/pen/XWpzerK?editors=0011

But I'm not sure why, I still get the "subType" even if my class doesn't defines it.

Comment: That is why in `fromJSON` function you are assigning `Object.assign(step, jsonObj);` and source `jsonObj` has the subType property... just remove it after `Object.assign` with `delete step.subType;`